# How to properly skip an iteration in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to `skip` an addition if the length of a string is equals to 4 but my code is giving me an error:

Here's my code:

```
strings = ["one", "two", "four", "abc", "fgh"]
total = strings.inject(0) do |sum, str|
  next if str.length == 4
 
  sum + str.length
end

puts total
```

and the error says:

```
main.rb:13:in `block in <main>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from main.rb:10:in `each'
        from main.rb:10:in `inject'
        from main.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

isn't the job of `next if`  to skip an iteration? Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `next` here because don't need `inject`. There is `sum` method (available in Ruby 2.4+ as I remember): `strings.sum { |str| str_length = str.length; str_length == 4 ? 0 : str_length }`. Or with `next 0`: `strings.sum { |str| str_length = str.length; next 0 if str_length == 4; str_length }`

Comment: You could also filter out the long strings before `inject`: `strings.select { |s| s.length < 4 }.inject { |sum, str| sum + str.length }` or even `strings.select { |s| s.length < 4 }.sum(&:length)`.

Comment: ...or `strings.filter_map { |s| s.length unless s.length == 4 }.sum`. @mu, time to get those skis waxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here occurs because when you call `next` you're passing nil to the next iteration of the loop.

```
strings = ["one", "two", "four", "abc", "fgh"]
total = strings.inject(0) do |sum, str|
  next sum if str.length == 4
  sum + str.length
end

# => 12
```

`next` doesn't actually skip the iteration. It just halts further execution of the block and has a return value.

Comment: when you say "passing nil" do you mean that ```sum``` becomes nil at the point during the iteration? when does the nil occur?

Comment: Not really. `next` works somewhat like `return` does in a method. It halts further execution of the block and unless you actually provide a return value it will pass nil to the next iteration of the block.

Comment: thank you for the explanation!

Comment: No worries. Just remember that `sum` is just a block variable that's either the initial value or the return value of the previous iteration. `sum + str.length` doesn't modify `sum`. It returns a new integer that is the implicit return from the block as it's the last expression.

Comment: The beginner-read-friendlier code might actually be the expansion
`if str.length == 4
  sum
else
  sum + str.length
end` (with proper indentation ;) ). But the `next` idiom is pretty common and I like to read it. But the fact that it has a return value makes it a bit more eye-unfriendly on `inject` and its friends imho.

Comment: The way you phrased it makes it sound as if `next` would set the next iteration value directly. It just returns from the block early, optionally providing a return value. The next iteration value becomes `nil` because `inject` keeps passing the block's return value into the next iteration.